# Когда срабатывает обработчик содержимое меняется только после обновления страницы?

Tags: php, cookie

Как сделать чтобы по нажатию submit'oв не приходилось дополнительно обновлять страницу и работало сразу после клика на кнопку?

Вот код :

```
<?php
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("my_bd");
//Обработка входа
if(isset($_POST['authorization']))
{
    $e_login = $_POST['e_login'];
    setcookie("e_login", $e_login, time()+3600);
        $e_password=md5($_POST['e_password']);
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE login='$e_login'");
        $user_data=mysql_fetch_array($query);

        if($user_data['password'] == $e_password){
            $check=true;                       
        }
        else{
            $check=false;
        }
}
//Обработка выхода
if(isset($_POST['logout']))
{
    $e_login=$_COOKIE['e_login'];
    setcookie("e_login", $e_login, time()-3600);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Работа с куками</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['e_login'])){
        echo "Кука существует(",$_COOKIE['e_login'],")<br>";
    echo "Авторизация прошла успешно";
    echo '<form method="post" action="22.php">
    Привет, '. $_COOKIE['e_login'].' <br>Хотите выйти? <br>
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Выйти" />
</form>';    
}
else{
    echo '<form method="post" action="22.php">
    Привет, Гость Пожалуйста авторизуйся <br>
    <input type="text" name="e_login" placeholder="e_login">
    <input type="text" name="e_password" placeholder="e_password">
    <input type="submit" name="authorization" value="Отправить" />
</form>';
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jquery Ajax

Comment: `setcookie` не проставляет значение в `$_COOKIE`, он просто создает HTTP-заголовок. Поэтому надо самому озаботиться, чтобы в `$_COOKIE` оказались нужные данные.

Comment: @terantul
а  

    header( 'Location: http://testwork/22.php');
можно воспользоваться?

Comment: header( 'Location - это та же перезагрузка страницы. Если требуется обновить/создать куки то потребуется перезагрузка страницы. Если от наличия/значения куки происходят изменения на странице (к примеру меняется информация о статусе пользователя залогинен или нет), можно после удачного создания куки так же через ажакс обновлять блок с информацией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

1. **signin.php** -- страница для ввода логина и пароля и ***submit*** на **signin-check.php**
2. **signin-check.php** -- страница для проверки логина и пароля, установка куков и/или значений сессиии, а также ***редирект*** на главную
3. **index.php** -- главная страница

Т.е. руками-то обновлять не потребуется, но без редиректа не обойтись.